# ConTeXt: text to the left of a numbered displayed formula

Tags: context

I read in an old style manual (*Sättningsregler*, by Lansburgh) that suggests to set short word(s) separating two displayed formulas (if there is space) to the left of the second displayed formula, as in the word "where" in the example picture below.

[image: example showing formula with "where" first in the second line]

As you see in the picture I am able to do what I want, but only with a "hack":

```
\defineformula[fix][
left=,
right=,
location=left,
]

\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=2bp]
\samplefile{ward} Thus
\startformula
xxxxxxxxxxx = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
\stopformula
\startplaceformula[title={where}]
\startfixformula
xxxxxx = xxx.
\stopfixformula
\stopplaceformula
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

The problem with this way of doing it is that the second formula cannot be numbered.

> **Question:** Is there a simple way to get the same result as above, but with the possibility to also number the equation?

Comment: Mathtools has \shortintertext, but is still leaves some space.  You might try the flaalign environment.  But since this is for ConTeXt, I can't say anything for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am hoping to not have to use the ConTeXt equivalent of `flalign`(?), since that will lead to a non-simple syntax. Also, the formula is supposed to be centered on its own (as if the text was not there), as in the image.

Comment: You could adjust `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip` inside a group, possibly making one negative.

Comment: Good idea! I guess that will work as long as no integrals or other big stuff is in the formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just insert a negative vertical space which compensates exactly the linebreak before the equation.

```
\startTEXpage

\samplefile{ward} Thus
\startformula
    xxxxxxxxxxx = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
\stopformula
where\blank[-line,force,overlay]
\startplaceformula
\startformula
    \int_a^b f(x) \, \diff x = F(b) - F(a) .
\stopformula
\stopplaceformula

\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

The misplaced equation number seems to be a bug (also in LMTX).

Comment: Many thanks, this clearly solves my problem, as stated. I saw the bug you mention in a big document when trying LMTX, but I was not able to produce a small document showing the problem by then.

Comment: @mickep You don't even need the negative `\blank` to get the misplaced number.  When LMTX was release I tried typesetting my master thesis from 2016 with it and found that everything is off.

Comment: Good. In the big file I do no such strange things, and the misplacement was clear. But I could not make a small "natural" example where it still was. Have you reported this to Hans? Do you have a very simple example without `\blank` and `\startTEXpage` and so on? I have not.

Comment: @mickep https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/094788.html